# Unity 2017 - Balloon spawner does not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am programming a 2D platformer where my main sprite jumps on randomly spawned bubbles/balloons. Below is the code I used. However, no balloons get generated at all but my other features in the game perfectly fine.

```
public class spawner2 : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] balloons;
public Vector3 spawnValues;
public float spawnWait;
public float spawnMostWait;
public float spawnLeastWait;
public int startWait;
public bool stop;

int randBalloon;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine (waitSpawner ());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    spawnWait = Random.Range (spawnLeastWait, spawnMostWait);   
}

IEnumerator waitSpawner()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);
    while (true) 
    {
        randBalloon = Random.Range (0, 5);
        //float randY = Random.Range(-0.25f,-2.25f);
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x),Random.Range(-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y),1);
        Instantiate ((balloons[randBalloon]),spawnPosition + transform.TransformPoint (0,0,0),gameObject.transform.rotation);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);

    }
}
```

The only error I get is:
[Press here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqxrg.png)
This is what I have in the inspector:
[The inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUnG5.png)
As a beginner in game development and in C# I would appreciate any help.

Comment: how big is your balloons array? has it been loaded through the inspector? you are getting this error because you are trying to instantiate a balloon in an index that does not exist. for example, spawning balloon  5 in an array that only has 4 objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ryeMoss. The size of the array is set to 2 and yes it has been loaded to the inspector (Image attached above). How can I make the index exist if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty straightforward.

Your balloons array contains 2 items, thus it has items in index 0 and index 1.

```
randBalloon = Random.Range (0, 5);
```

Generates a random number, ranging from 0 to 4 (the second parameter is an exclusive int).

So, your spawner will regulary try to access index 2, 3 and 4 which are all indices that do not exist and therefore results in an index out of range exception.

You can easilly fix it by using this:

```
randBalloon = Random.Range (0, balloons.Length - 1);
```

balloons.Length will return an int of 2 in your case, because it gives you the length of your array. Since you need 0 to reference the first item of an array and not 1, we add the "-1". This way, you can never get an index out of range exception.